# Clock source controlled by the logic that is being clocked by the source

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, vivado, kintex-series-fpga

What are the implications when an always block controls the switch that will change the clock source(actually more than one frequency coming from a clock divider) that is clocking the always block? How will the synthesis tool handle the timing? How should the constraints be given in such a case?

Example :

```
assign clk = (freq_val=='d0) ? clk_5M : (freq_val=='d1) ? clk_10M : clk_200M
always@(posedge clk) begin
   if(cond1) freq_val='d0;
   else if(cond2) freq_val<='d1;
   else freq_val<='d0;
end
```

Comment: The advantage of synchronous logic is that there is a 'universal base' for all the signals in the system to be measured upon, and that universal base is the clock. If you are just learning treat the clock signal as a sacred thing that is not to be touched, altered, or generated by logic. Once you have experience you can 'commit the sin' of passing clock signals thru logic. But until that day: DO NOT TOUCH THE CLOCK. DO NOT USE CLOCKS COMING FROM LOGIC. First learn what clock enable signals are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you will need to constrain for the fastest timing.  You have described a Mux, so you should get a Mux in synthesis.  You need more "protection" with respect to what @Oldfart stated in terms of "runt pulses"

Google "Techniques to make clock switching glitch free".  There is a IEEE article with that tile that should help.

Consider a "blanking time" when switching clock frequency...  when you switch your mux, delay the clock switching to the new frequency until you have removed/blocked/gated the clock output.  Once it has "settled" to the new frequency, then reapply it.  If you don't need the previous values, you might as well apply a reset to the effected parts of the design when you switch.

Comment: The idea is to serially shift data into a set of registers at a slower frequency, then parallely load them into another set of registers at higher frequency.(Offchip).The offchip and onchip logic uses the same clock as reference.The number of clock pulses should be exact.  I could gate the shift registers clock until after I have switched the clock, but since the clocks are synchronous I was hoping this wouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Sounds like you just need two clock domains of logic, not two clocks for all the logic(?)  Store serially at first frequency, transmit parallel at other frequency.  likely this is a "simple" as using an asynchronous FIFO.  

BTW, the clocks, by definition, are not synchronous if they have different frequencies... They may be correlated in terms of having an aligned edge at times, but not synchronous (unfortunately, the term "synchronous" is misused all the time, it only serves to confuse).

Comment: The setup is like this. I have a 'component' connected to my FPGA.(Sorry for non-specific terms!). The component has set of Scan Flipflops that can be configured as a long shift register or as a 'FIFO' like you mentioned. The serial path has timing issues in the component so I am forced to do it slowly, but the output of the 'FIFO' is supposed to drive a bus at higher frequency. My confusion was how to give timing constraints for the FPGA in this case. I will constrain it to the highest frequency like you said. Here what I meant by synchronous is that I am switching the clocks synchronously.

Answer (score 3):

This :
   `assign clk = (freq_val=='d0) ? clk_5M : (freq_val=='d1) ? clk_10M : clk_200M`
is dangerous. <sub>And wrong as you can't get clk_200M out of that but I assume that is just a typo</sub>

You must make sure that you do not generate 'runt' clock pulses. (Clock pulses which are too short high or low).

If all those clocks are synchronous and have coinciding rising edges you may get away with that. If they are a-synchronous it will not work.

Beware that your code may work perfectly in a simulation but can fail on real hardware!

Comment: All the clocks i.e, clk_5M,clk_10M etc are just divided clocks derived from free running counter that is clocked by the clk_200M.So I believe they have coinciding edges and are Synchronous  to each other. I am not quite sure what you mean by 'runt'  clock pulses because, suppose logic is running at 200MHz and I want to switch to 5MHz, next clock edge should be atleast 5ns away, since 5Mhz is derived from 200Mhz clock. Similar is the case for 5M to 200M. Am I right?

Comment: Your MUX has to switch between two inputs. Depending on how it is build it could momentarily have a zero value in between. (No input selected) which gives you a 'runt' low clock period of a few ps...ns.